# iphone - performSelectorOnMainThread with return value

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I have the following method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getElements:(NSString *)theURL;
```

And I wanted to know if there is a way to call that method using performSelectorOnMainThread so that I can get the return value. So far, I've tried with:

```
myArray = [object performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getElements:)
                                   withObject:url waitUntilDone:YES];
```

but it doesn't work, since performSelectorOnMainThread returns void. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Welcome to a multi-threaded environment my friend.

You'll need to store the return value in an instance variable or pass in an object by reference through the `withObject` parameter:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict;

[object performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(getElements:)
                                   withObject:&myDict waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Your method prototype should now look like this:

```
- (void)getElements:(NSMutableDictionary **)objects;
```

Comment: This fails to compile with: "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an rvalue of type 'NSMutableDictionary **'"

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it directly, because, as you say, that method returns void.

So, you'd have to arrange another way to get a value back, for example by passing an NSDictionary instead of an NSString, and having the method store the result in the dictionary for you.

Answer (score 3):

Had to implement this recently. Great candidate for adding a category to NSObject so that all your objects can do this:

```
@implementation NSObject (CallSelectorWithObjectOnMainThread)
- (id)resultFromSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)selector object:(id)object {
  NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
  NSMutableDictionary *callDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:resultDictionary, @"ResultDictionary", NSStringFromSelector(selector), @"Selector", nil];
  if(object) [callDict setValue:object forKey:@"Object"];
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(callObject:) withObject:callDict waitUntilDone:YES];
  return [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"Result"];
}

- (void)callObject:(NSMutableDictionary *)info {
  id result;
  SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([info objectForKey:@"Selector"]);
  id object = [info objectForKey:@"Object"];
  NSMutableDictionary *resultDictionary = [info objectForKey:@"Dictionary"];
  if(object)
    result = [self performSelector:selector withObject:object];
  else
    result = [self performSelector:selector];
  if(result)
    [resultDictionary setValue:result forKey:@"Result"];
}
@end
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for this Colin. I found a couple defects after using it: callDict needs to be initialized with NSMutableDictionary and callObject needs to have an NSMutableDictionary method argument.

Answer (score 2):

I have universal solution for async blocking call with return value for any thread, not only main. This example for main thread like performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

```
__block id result = nil;
NSOperationQueue* targetQueue = [NSOperationQueue* mainQueue];
// targetQueue is main thread, but it may be queue on any thread.

[targetQueue addBlockOperation:^{
    // performs on target thread.
    result = [someObject someSelector];
}];

// wait until operations on targetQueue will finished.
[targetQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

// result is ready here.
```

I used this technique only in ARC environment.